# Android ViewPager child fragments load but tabs don't

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using a ViewPager in a fragment that loads a child fragment per tab, and that is working fine the child fragments are loaded, but the issue is that the tabs themselves, where the tab click-able names go, is not showing, nor is it responding to click events. I reach this screen by selecting an element in a recyclerview in a previous fragment.

The expected layout structure is the following: 
[image: Expected Layout]

But the problem is that, although everything else loads fine and I can side swipe to switch child fragments, the tab bar doesn't load at all and I just get this:

[image: Current Flawed layout]

I'm not sure what is causing this, but when I rotate the screen and back, then they appear.

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static int PROFILE_FRAGMENT = 1;
private final static int PRIZES_FRAGMENT = 2;
private final static int STORES_FRAGMENT = 3;
private final static int ABOUT = 4;
private int currentFragment = 3;
private String currentFragmentName = "StoresListFragment";
public int HEADER_IMAGE = R.drawable.avatar;

private DrawerLayout drawer;
private List<DrawerItem> dataList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("STORE_DETAILS") != null) {
        openFragment(new StoreDetailsFragment());
        setTitle(getString(R.string.title_store_details));
    }
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (mToolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    addItemsToDataList();
    NavDrawerAdapter mAdapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(dataList, this, db.getClientName(), db.getPoints(), HEADER_IMAGE);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    drawer.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };
    drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    onTouchDrawer(currentFragment);
    final GestureDetector mGestureDetector =
            new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

            if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                drawer.closeDrawers();
                onTouchDrawer(recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
}

private void addItemsToDataList() {
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem(getString(R.string.title_profile), R.mipmap.ic_action_profile));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem(getString(R.string.title_prizes), R.mipmap.ic_action_prizes));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem(getString(R.string.title_stores), R.mipmap.ic_action_sales));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem(getString(R.string.title_about), R.mipmap.ic_action_about));
}

public void openFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    if (!fragment.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(currentFragmentName)) {
        // update the transfer content by replacing fragments
        currentFragmentName = fragment.toString();
        switchContent(fragment);
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

private void onTouchDrawer(final int position) {
    currentFragment = position;
    switch (position) {
        case PROFILE_FRAGMENT:
            openFragment(new ProfileFragment());
            setTitle(getString(R.string.title_profile));
            break;
        case PRIZES_FRAGMENT:
            openFragment(new PrizesListFragment());
            setTitle(getString(R.string.title_prizes));
            break;
        case STORES_FRAGMENT:
            openFragment(new StoresListFragment());
            setTitle(getString(R.string.title_stores));
            break;
        case ABOUT:
            openFragment(new AboutFragment());
            setTitle(getString(R.string.title_about));
            break;
        default:
    }
}

/*
 * helper to switch content with backstack
 */
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    // add to backstack
            .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("SALES_LIST") != null) {
        openFragment(new StoreDetailsFragment());
        setTitle(getString(R.string.title_store_details));

    } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() <= 0) {
        openFragment(new StoresListFragment());
        setTitle(getString(R.string.title_stores));
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

The fragment in question:

```
public class StoreDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private Store storeSelected = null;
private TextView storeName;
private ImageView bannerImage;
private TextView storesubtitle;

public StoreDetailsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_details, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabanim_viewpager);
    TabLayout storeTabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabanim_tabs);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    storeTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    storeTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sales List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Store Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Store Ratings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    bannerImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.store_details_banner_image);
    storeName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_store_details_name);
    storesubtitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_store_details_subtitle);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set title
    getMainActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_store_details);
}

protected MainActivity getMainActivity() {
    return (MainActivity) getActivity();
}
```

}

Fragment in question's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/store_details_banner_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/white_placeholder"
                android:contentDescription=""
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/smth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_store_details_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_store_details_subtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_action_store_house"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#333"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabanim_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#F1514A"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="#99ffffff"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the ViewPagerAdaper:

```
public class StoreDetailsViewPagerTabAdaper extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public StoreDetailsViewPagerTabAdaper(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFrag(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}}
```

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I couldn't find a solution to this and even after consulting some more experienced developers we could only find a workaround, which was just have this be inside an activity instead of a fragment and then the viewpager behaves as expected. I couldn't figure out why it doesn't inside a fragment.
If anyone finds a more suitable answer, go ahead, but until then I'll set this to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
```

Try this one and initiate your adapter with getChildFragmentManager

Comment: @ohm update your library, most of the bugs of 23.0.0 is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I would try to log inside getPageTitle, because I think when you rotate the screen everything is destroyed an the mFragmentTitleList is empty when you redraw the titles, so try to find out what's going on by doing something like:

```
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    Log.d("ViewPagerAdapter", "Displaying title: "+ mFragmentTitleList.get(position));
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
```

Comment: I tested it, and the correct titles are shown in the log, both when they aren't showing on screen and when I rotate and they reappear, so the information is there, it's just not being displayed for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TabLayout` might not be showing because you set height to it. Try setting  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

You don't have to handle tab clicks manually – if you bind the `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

the listener is created automatically. I would suggest to remove the custom listener.

Comment: I set the tablayout height to be the same as the toolbar so that it fills the toolbar space and doesn't get squished, but I tested with wrap _content and the problem remained. Also, I just set that listener so I could test if he tabs were switching properly on side swipe, since I couldn't click the tabs, but you're correct, I should use the automatically created one.